# Elasticsearch sort by first element of array

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch 5.5 and have an index with such mapping:

```
{
  "my_index": {
    "mappings": {
      "my_type": {
        "properties": {
          "title": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "my_array": {
            "properties": {
              "array": {
                "type": "float"
              },
              "length": {
                "type": "long"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to search by title and sort by first value from array. Also it would be great to set this first value to the `_score` field. 
So, I've prepared such request:

```
GET my_index/my_type/_search
{
    "query": {
      "term": {
        "title.keyword": "Shorts"
      }
    }, 
    "sort" : {
        "_script" : {
            "type" : "number",
            "script" : {
                "lang": "painless",
                "inline": "doc['my_array.array'][0]"
            },
            "order" : "asc"
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. I feel something is missing or wrong.

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: @HatimStovewala There is no error, but the order is wrong

Comment: May you please provide some example documents and the response? What do you expect to be in the response and what is there actually? Thank you.

Comment: @NikolayVasiliev With such request: GET my_index/my_type/_search { "sort" : { "_script" : { "type" : "number", "script" : { "lang": "painless", "inline": "doc['embeddings.array'][0]" }, "order" : "asc" } } } The response is https://jsonblob.com/05e5893a-be1c-11e7-9ae8-cdd8d94a615d

Comment: Does this valid way to access first element of array `doc['my_array.array'][0]` ?

Comment: As far as I see there is the largest number on the first place of array? How it could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Andrei](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47040381/5095957) pointed out in his answer, you should refer directly to `_source` in your painless script.

This happens because in the Lucene index (which is what ElasticSearch is built upon) does not have a notion of original order of the values in your array. Moreover, [arrays do not work as you would expect](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html):

> Arrays of objects do not work as you would expect: you cannot query
>   each object independently of the other objects in the array.

Basically, you are sorting by a random number from your list.

What Andrei is suggesting is to use the [`_source`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html), which is, to read the original JSON document, parse it and extract the needed value from there (it will work). But `_source` is slow (because instead of accessing fast index you read from the disk, every time, every document).

You have 2 other options:

- move this first element as a separate field;
- use [`nested` data type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) and explicitly define order.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

The correct way of using that Painless script is like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "title.keyword": "Shorts"
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type": "number",
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "inline": "params._source.my_array.array[0]"
      },
      "order": "asc"
    }
  }
}
```